# No aparecen las propiedades de vista en Storyboard support

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

Hola he estado batallando desde inicié a programar en iOS con el uso de las Pods en los proyectos, un ejemplo es cuando instalo sin problemas la Pod de Floaty y al hacer uso de ella no me aparecen las propiedades de la vista y así poder darle diseño a mi botón.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He apuntado en la vista a la clase que pertenece de la siguiente manera, pero no logro hacer que aparezcan las propiedades.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así debería de aparecer pero no logro saber por que no aparece de esta manera cómo se visualiza en el repositorio de Github https://github.com/kciter/Floaty:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto no solo sucede con esta librería si no al igual que todas las que he instalado, como ejemplo las de MaterialComponents, alguien puede ayudarme por favor si le ha ocurrido algo similar ya que llevo tiempo batallando con ello y no logro encontrar una solución de raíz.

- La versión de Xcode es: Version 10.1 (10B61)
- La versión de cocoapods es: cocoapods-1.5.3
- La versión de ruby es: ruby 2.3.7p456

Comment: si los pods son de 32 bits, ya están deprecados para Xcode 10... ya solo se están aceptando pods de 64 bits, por lo que no están funcionando correctamente o simplemente no funcionan, hay pods que ya no están siendo actualizados y esos ya no están funcionando, checa bien cuando fue la ultima modificación de los pods que estas usando... o tal vez sea un bug... quizá reinstalando Xcode te solucione el problema... que ojalá sea eso un bug....

Comment: la otra, intenta darle las propiedades en el código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando la librería que comentas Floaty para poder editar los atributos en el storyboard, se deben de declarar el apartado de "User Defined Runtime Attributes" como adjunto en la imagen1.Los cambios pueden no verse reflejados inmediatamente para esto hay dos opciones; una teniendo seleccionada la opción "Automatically Refresh Views" o dar clic en "Refresh All Views"

[image: imagen1]

[image: imagen2]

En cuanto a que no aparezcan visibles en la ventana de "Attributes inspector" es debido a la declaración que hace la librería en su clase Floaty.swift ya que es declarada de la forma :

```
@IBInspectable
@objc open var plusColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1)
```

Si modificamos borrando la compatibilidad "@objc" dichas declaraciones quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
@IBInspectable
open var plusColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1)
```

Podrás visualizar las propiedades en la ventana de "Attributes inspector" como se visualiza en la la imagen3
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias me  ha funcionado, saludos.